# Drupal Commerce Paypal WPS - Connection refused

Tags: 7, commerce, payment-gateways

I am trying to get the WPS module to work for Drupal Commerce but I am getting an error. After the payment is made in my logs I see.

> Attempt to validate IPN failed with error -111: Connection refused

The code that this relates to in the pay pal module is:

```
// Process the HTTP request to validate the IPN.
$response = drupal_http_request($host, array('method' => 'POST', 'data' => implode('&', $variables)));

// If an error occurred during processing, log the message and exit.
if (property_exists($response, 'error')) {
  watchdog('commerce_paypal', 'Attempt to validate IPN failed with error @code: @error', array('@code' => $response->code, '@error' => $response->error), WATCHDOG_ERROR);
  return FALSE;
}
```

The `$response` has an error in it (Connection refused).

As I am using the sandbox the `$host` is `https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr`.

I can confirm that I do receive the IPN from PayPal (some `dd()` statements proved this), but when we check to see if PayPal sent it, the code falls over.

Any ideas what could be going wrong? I am preusming it is more likley to be enviromental rather than code.

Answer (score 1):

**This was an environmental problem**. The Drupal server did not have a direct connection to the internet. Setting the proxy settings in `settings.php` got this to work.

http://devincarlson.ca/blog/configuring-drupal-use-proxy-server-when-making-external-http-requests

In my case the settings I had to set were:

```
$conf['proxy_server'] = 'my server';
$conf['proxy_port'] = 1234; // port number
```